# Put Margin in Div

Tags: html, css

I have a doubt . When I'm trying put margin in the second div. Why element all element include his father take this margin ? I just want the child div to have the margin and be separated from the parent container. Thanks everybody!

```css
#divFather {
    height:100px;
    width:800px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:blue;
}
#divChild {
    height:50px;
    width:400px;
                 /* margin: 15px 0px */
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="divFather">
             <div id="divChild">Margin</div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding any dimension be it margin, padding, width, height border etc increses the actual size of an element thereby increasing the size of its containing parent.

Comment: please don't use the answer you accept in a real project, that's not the correct way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the margin overlap problem of static positioned elements. This could be fixed by adding `position: relative;` to the parent element and `position: absolute` to the child element.

```css
#divFather {
    height:100px;
    width:800px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:blue;
    position: relative;
}
#divChild {
    height:50px;
    width:400px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="divFather">
             <div id="divChild">Margin</div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's the worst ever way to fix the issue. You are creating a bigger issue

Answer (score 3):

This is called [Collapsing margins](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins). You can read more about this in attached link. To fix this you can use either `use padding on parent element` or another approach is to `set overflow to auto` of parent div.

Comment: I had no knowledge about Collapsing margins , thanks bro!